# Appcelerator Studio LiveView recompile error

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, titanium-alloy, appcelerator-titanium

Constantly getting this error when LiveView is trying to recompile. Can anyone shed some light on how the LiveView works? The object "Alloy.Globals.layout.activityList" DOES exist, but perhaps the LiveView only recompile parts of the code where Alloy Globals doesn't exist?

```
[ERROR] :  Script Error {
[INFO] :   {
[ERROR] :      column = 36;
[ERROR] :      line = 28;
[ERROR] :      message = "undefined is not an object (evaluating 'Alloy.Globals.layout.activityList')";
```

The "Movies" example app from Appcelerator uses the same logic of having a layout object in Alloy.js. Im doing the exact same thing, but its messing upp the recompile about 8 out of 10 times.

```
/**
 * Calculate element dimensions for given screen size
 * @param {Object} size   containing width and height properties
 */
Alloy.Globals.calculateElementDimensions = function(size) {

  var layout = {};

  layout.device = {};
  layout.device.width = size.width;
  layout.device.height = size.height;

  // lists
  layout.activityList = {};
  layout.activityList.cell = {};

  layout.activityList.cell.width = size.width;
  layout.activityList.cell.height = 60;
  layout.activityList.cell.spacing = 1;

  layout.activityList.cell.dateView = {};
  layout.activityList.cell.dateView.width = layout.activityList.cell.height;
  layout.activityList.cell.dateView.height = layout.activityList.cell.height;

  layout.activityList.cell.detailsView = {};
  layout.activityList.cell.detailsView.width = (layout.activityList.cell.width - layout.activityList.cell.dateView.width) - 50;
  layout.activityList.cell.detailsView.height = layout.activityList.cell.height;

  layout.activityList.cell.deleteView = {};
  layout.activityList.cell.deleteView.width = size.width * 0.2;
  layout.activityList.cell.deleteView.right = (0 - layout.activityList.cell.deleteView.width);
  return layout;
};

// Calculate element dimentsions
Alloy.Globals.layout = Alloy.Globals.calculateElementDimensions(Alloy.Globals.Device);
Alloy.Globals.getCalculatedWidth = function(_percentage){
  return (Alloy.Globals.Device.width * (_percentage / 100));
};
```

## #Update

I think I might have found whats triggering the error. It seems its not actually a problem with running the new updated code, but rather that there is an error before the shut down and refresh.

```
**[INFO] :   [LiveView] Reloading App**
[INFO] :   Login win close
[INFO] :   XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
[INFO] :   validateLogInInfo
[INFO] :   XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
[INFO] :   UI SHUTDOWN COMPLETE. TRYING TO RESUME RESTART
[INFO] :   XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
[INFO] :   RUNNING CODE IN ACTIVITIES.JS
[INFO] :   XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
**[ERROR] :  Script Error {
[ERROR] :      column = 36;
[ERROR] :      line = 42;
[ERROR] :      message = "undefined is not an object (evaluating 'Alloy.Globals.layout.device')";
[ERROR] :      stack = "Controller\ncreateController\nController\ncreateController\nvalidateLogInInfo\n";
[ERROR] :  }
Alloy.createController('login', {
    callback: validateLogInInfo
  }).getView().open();**
```

The error seem to have to do with that I am running code in the window.close event handler. For example in one controller I do this:

```
  Alloy.createController('login', {
    callback: validateLogInInfo
  }).getView().open();
```

And in login.js i do:

```
$.win.addEventListener('close', function(){
  log('Login win close');
  args.callback();
});
```

I guess the callback is then trying to run when LiveView is trying to close down and refresh, hence the compiler error. Removing the callback in the windoew.close event results in a successful reload

```
[INFO] :   [LiveView] Reloading App
[INFO] :   Login win close
[INFO] :   UI SHUTDOWN COMPLETE. TRYING TO RESUME RESTART
```

SO, is providing a callback to the close event of an other controller completely the wrong way to do this stuff?

Comment: Are you sure that **layout** variable inside your **calculateElementDimensions** method contains the key-value pair of **activityList**?

Comment: Please post the original code since this is a subtle code error and then we can help you find the error.

Comment: It does, and the values does work through out the app when I do a normal "Run" of the project.

I updated the code above to contain my code from alloy.js and not from the Movies example app.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the code seems correct. Try to run the app in LiveView mode and in Trace Console mode and then see if there is something else which is causing this issue.[image]

See image to set Trace mode.

Comment: Thanks for updated question. The error is reasonable because you are using **args** variable when it is not available for **login.js** window. So, the correct way to do this is that do not call callback method in event listener, rather call it before closing the window. Now, if you think that how would you know when the window is closing, then you can simply write onClick event for back button in both iOS and Android.

Comment: Yep, thats correct. To further mess it up I opened a new controller in the callback. Now I changed to just call args.callback() followed by $.win.close()

Comment: Great! That's the correct way to perform anything before closing the window. Usually we think in beginning that onClose event will fire up when the window is about to close, but nowadays we need to run the code before closing a window in almost every app, so it's better to over-ride the close events correctly. Good Luck !!!!